# TSQL - LEFT JOIN strange results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am coming across an issue with the results of a seemingly basic query (on SQL Server 2017 CU17), and am hoping that people could suggest some things that I may not have checked or tried to get the correct results out.

The premise of the issue is that I am attempting to identify rows in one table, where an ID exists in another. This can usually be done with a LEFT JOIN, in this case, the query is as simple as follows:

```
SELECT  t1.id,
        t2.id
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

This query should identify rows that exist in Table1 that do not exist in Table2, based on the 'id' columns, and is running against static data that isn't being manipulated in any way when I run the query.

[image: LEFT JOIN query results image]

I am getting a strange result from this, where rows are being returned where t1.id is returned, but t2.id is NULL - as if there are rows that exist in t1, but not t2. 
However, if I take one of the IDs returned from the first query, and manually check if it exists in both tables, it looks like the id does exist in both - even if I put that id into a query with an inner join such as follows:

```
SELECT  t1.id,
        t2.id
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 761179370
```

[image: INNER JOIN query results for a given ID image]

If I run the LEFT JOIN query a number of times, I get a different number of rows returned each time.
Important to note that the id columns are both int datatypes, and the tables have the exact same collation.

What I have tried:

- I have rebuilt statistics on all columns and indexes for each table to see if that was causing some issues.
- I have restored the database on to another server and ran the same, and do not get the problem I am seeing above. The DB is in an availability group and I have also run the same query on the readable secondary, and am not seeing the same behaviour.
- The server I ran the LEFT JOIN query is on, is a busy server overall - could this be a factor in why the query is not returning the correct results?
- I have tried with ANSI_NULLS both on and off, no difference.

Any idea what the problem may be, or what I could check to figure out why I am getting these results - any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: One possibility is that the data is simply changing, so there are no stable results.  Another is that the tables are really views that do not return stable results.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. They are definitely tables and not views. I have tested the query at a time where the data is static, and nothing is changing it, even to the point of changing isolation level of my query to hold a lock on the tables for the duration of the query.

Comment: @JamesG, if possible make a copy of the tables in question (or a slice of them if they are large) so the tables won't receive updates. Then retry the tests, I think Gordon is spot on, but that'd be one way to confirm this.

Comment: @JamesG What is the result of query `SELECT  t1.id,
        t2.id
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.id = 761179370` ? I changed t1 to t2 in `WHERE`

Comment: @Ryan - I have restored the database on to new servers - and I do not see the same issue, so the issue seems to be with the one server that happens to be in production. What Gordon has suggested is the first thing I tested a few days ago, ensuring that the data is static.

Comment: @Robert - Results for your altered query appear the same as the image above, doesn't matter which table I reference in the WHERE clause. The row exists in both tables, so that is working as expected.

Comment: Do you still have the database on the other server that works? compare the execution plan between the two servers and see if it can provide a lead.

Comment: @Frank - Yes, this is one of the first things checked! Sadly, the execution plans are identical. Costs differ of course, but that is expected.

Comment: @JamesG. Are those Id really INT on both table? I had issues a few time where one side was VARCHAR and the other side was CHARS from two ETL import. SQLSVR doesn't always cast them to the type you expect consistently. it uses the first 10 record to sniff the type.

Comment: @FrankChen - Yep, both columns are definitely int.

Comment: @JamesG the last common thing I can think of is that you are out of temp disk space. Either it can't expand of has been capped on that server.

Comment: Try a DBCC CHECKTABLE to see if any of the indexes are corrupted.

Comment: Thanks @RazvanSocol - no errors found on integrity checks.

Comment: Dumb question, I've done something similar. What I realized was I joined on ColumnA, but selected ColumnB because ColumnA  and ColumnB had very similar names. Are you sure you have the correct column names?

Comment: Is the behaviour the same using select id from t1 except select id from t2?

Answer (score 1):

If you post the real query we may see a mistake there, **check the query another time**, some condition in the left join can change the "usual logic".

If still wrong, try this:

```
SELECT
t1.id,
t2.id
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
option (recompile) --> This will ignore any cached data
```

Or create 2 temps to store some data and test there, database in production may change the results very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem a while ago. The reason was, that the SQL-Server Management Studio had cached some of the results. The famous off and on again did solve my problem. Your experiments pretty much say this wasnt the case, so ..

Here i would suggest comparing the results to the following:

```
SELECT  t1.id FROM Table1 AS t1
where t1.id not in (select id from table2)
```

If these results dont match with your query i would suggest a restart.

PS: Sorry for not using the comment, i have not enough reputation for that. :-\

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you have that issue you can paste the value on Notepad++ to validate that there is no other char or something similar added to the second one.

You can try the `(NOLOCK)` to avoid this kind of behavior, something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TABLE1 T1 (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 (NOLOCK) -- LEFT JOIN IS THE SAME AS LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```